# extract coordinates on interactive map in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, geocoding

I have a question and I need to clarify if this is possible in Shiny with Rstudio.

I know that we can plot locations (latitude and longitude) on a map, but can we do the opposite? I mean, if we have a map and by clicking on the map at a specific spatial point, can we extract the coordinates and save them as vectors or in a CSV file?

I was looking for examples but I only found examples on how to plot locations on a map:

```
# get map
newmap <- getMap(resolution = "low")
# plot map
plot(newmap, xlim = c(-20, 59), ylim = c(35, 71), 
     asp = 1, fill = T, border = "darkgray", 
     col = "wheat2", bg = "gray95")
# add points
points(airports$Longitude, airports$Latitude, col = "red", cex = .5, pch = 20)
```

Any thoughts on whether this approach is possible in Shiny with a clickable map?
Thank you!

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html